# Check if the header is custom

Tags: python, http, flask

is there a way in python to check if request header is custom or just default? Literally is it possible to differentiate these 2 curl requests?

```
curl -si 127.0.0.1:8080/api/key1 -XPUT -d '{"text": "hello"}'

curl -si 127.0.0.1:8080/api/key1 -XPUT -d '{"text": "hello"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Comment: Yes, you can analyze the headers. Play with the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module.

Comment: but using request.headers.get('Content-Type') gives same string on both

Comment: You need to define a custom header then. Content-Type is a supported header, so you will have it both header requests. The value of content-type is the already set default. So what exactly are you looking to figure out? Can you give a more concrete example of what you mean by custom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this in flask or in any language/framework. A request is just a string sent over the HTTP protocol, and any two requests with the same string are equivalent.  By default, the Content-Type of a PUT request in curl is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Specifying this content type specifically will result in curl sending off the same string over HTTP.

Proof

```
curl -si https://httpbin.org/put -X PUT -d '{"text": "hello"}' > test1

curl -si https://httpbin.org/put -X PUT -d '{"text": "hello"}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' > test2

diff test1 test2 # Only the dates and processing times differ
```

Comment: If I set `x=y` as a header value in the second request, you are telling me that there is no way I can determine that both requests are different by also realizing that my custom setting in that header is not in the other request? The original example in the question is not using a custom header.

Comment: You most definitely would, I interpreted this question to be asking about overriding default values, which is what the example showed.  Setting header x equal to y would clearly create a different request, but does not disagree with what I've written in this post. Your two requests would have different strings.

Comment: This is what I find confusing about the question. Both the key and the value are *the* default settings for the request. I'm just having difficulty understanding because of the mention of *custom* when *custom* was not used in the question at all. Granted, yes, your answer based explicitly on the fact that there is no custom header data being set is correct.

Comment: Custom may not have been the right word for me to use, but I was trying to stay consistent with OPs language.  It does ask "is there a way in python to check if request header is custom or just default," so I used the word custom same as them

Comment: @David Agreed, yes. My "custom" comment was more about the confusion I have from the question, not the answer.